# AWS S3 to Google Cloud Storage Transfer not working with Python Client Library because "precondition check failed"

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, transfer

I tried testing out cloud transfer function that would transfer an object from AWS S3 to GCS (as a one-off task) but I keep getting `googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://storagetransfer.googleapis.com/v1/transferJobs?alt=json returned "Precondition check failed.">`.

Here is the code:

```
import argparse
import datetime
import json
from pprint import pprint

import googleapiclient.discovery


def main(description, project_id, year, month, day, hours, minutes,
         source_bucket, access_key, secret_access_key, sink_bucket):
    """Create a one-off transfer from Amazon S3 to Google Cloud Storage."""
    storagetransfer = googleapiclient.discovery.build('storagetransfer', 'v1')

    # Edit this template with desired parameters.
    # Specify times below using US Pacific Time Zone.
    transfer_job = {
        'description': description,
        'status': 'ENABLED',
        'projectId': project_id,
        'schedule': {
            'scheduleStartDate': {
                'day': day,
                'month': month,
                'year': year
            },
            'scheduleEndDate': {
                'day': day,
                'month': month,
                'year': year
            },
            'startTimeOfDay': {
                'hours': hours,
                'minutes': minutes
            }
        },
        'transferSpec': {
            'awsS3DataSource': {
                'bucketName': source_bucket,
                'awsAccessKey': {
                    'accessKeyId': access_key,
                    'secretAccessKey': secret_access_key
                }
            },
            'gcsDataSink': {
                'bucketName': sink_bucket
            }
        }
    }

    result = storagetransfer.transferJobs().create(body=transfer_job).execute()
    print('Returned transferJob: {}'.format(
        json.dumps(result, indent=4)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description=__doc__,
        formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument('description', help='Transfer description.')
    parser.add_argument('project_id', help='Your Google Cloud project ID.')
    parser.add_argument('date', help='Date YYYY/MM/DD.')
    parser.add_argument('time', help='Time (24hr) HH:MM.')
    parser.add_argument('source_bucket', help='Source bucket name.')
    parser.add_argument('access_key', help='Your AWS access key id.')
    parser.add_argument('secret_access_key', help='Your AWS secret access '
                        'key.')
    parser.add_argument('sink_bucket', help='Sink bucket name.')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(args.date, '%Y/%m/%d')
    time = datetime.datetime.strptime(args.time, '%H:%M')

    main(
        args.description,
        args.project_id,
        date.year,
        date.month,
        date.day,
        time.hour,
        time.minute,
        args.source_bucket,
        args.access_key,
        args.secret_access_key,
        args.sink_bucket)
```

And here is the command I used to execute it:

`python cloud_transfer_test.py "cloudtransfer" "MY_PROJECT_ID" "2018/04/12" "09:17" "SOURCE_BUCKET" "ACCESS_KEY" "SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" "SINK_BUCKET"`

*Note: ACCESS_KEY and SECRET_ACCESS_KEY actually had values but I'm omiting them from this post. Also the date and time values are configured such that it runs as soon as I execute the script.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect your problem will turn out to be the permissions for the not-obviously needed xxx@storage-transfer-service.iam.gserviceaccount.com

You can find out the name of the account you need using the storage transfer get call in the API explorer 
https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/reference/rest/v1/googleServiceAccounts/get

The needed permissions are documented at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-transfer

Be careful setting these; when I had this problem I had set them, but apparently not correctly, and after I went back to looking at them it still took me a couple tries before it worked. If they are not set correctly on the destination bucket/project you will get the precondition failed error.

Comment: Note that if you are transferring from GCP to GCP you also need to give this account permission on the source bucket.